# Sybase CTE in update

Tags: sybase, common-table-expression

Could someone help why such update does't work on `sybase`

```
with cte (col1,col2)
as (...),

cte_2 as (...)

update d
set d.car = t.car
from data d
join cte t on d.id = t.id
```

Comment: Please edit your question so as to precise what you mean by *doesn't work*

Comment: which Sybase product (ASE? SQLAnywhere? IQ? Advantage?) and version?

Comment: SAP iq/16.0.110

Answer (score 0):

This syntax does not work because it is not supported by the database engine. Please refer to official documentation for supported syntax for the UPDATE command.